# How retrieve results in a sparql endpoint based on the URI

Tags: uri, sparql, json-ld

I am trying to do a sparql query in the [sparql endpoint from the Dutch goverment](https://data.pdok.nl/sparql).

My wish is being able to retrieve a building based on a given identifier which I have (for example '100174287')

When I randomly click on one of the results of another query and assess the output of the query in json-ld format, I see that the URI of each building is stored in the following line

```
,"@id":"http://brt.basisregistraties.overheid.nl/top10nl/id/gebouw/100174287"
```

My question is how I explicitly can retrieve this building when I now beforehand that the URI contains the following numbers: '**100174287**'. 
I tried it with the following predicates with a ***filter*** and/ or ***regex*** function, but without avail.

- top10NL@id
- [top10NL:identificatie](https://brt.basisregistraties.overheid.nl/def/top10nl#identificatie) this property should be inherited by the Building class, but for some reason it doesn't succeed in retrieving an URI when I use this as a predicate.

I tried the following query to no avail

```
PREFIX top10nl: <http://brt.basisregistraties.overheid.nl/def/top10nl#>
SELECT ?x WHERE {
 ?x a top10nl:Gebouw.
  ?x top10nl:identificatie ?identificatie.
  Filter (?identificatie= '102046456')
}
LIMIT 100
```

Based on the suggestion of AKSW, I managed to select a building based on an identifier, however when I try to elaborate the query, I get a timeout error.
I am not sure whether it has something to do with my query or with the [sparql endpoint](https://data.pdok.nl/sparql) itself.

```
PREFIX top10nl: <http://brt.basisregistraties.overheid.nl/def/top10nl#>
PREFIX brt: <http://brt.basisregistraties.overheid.nl/def/top10nl#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
prefix geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
PREFIX uom: <http://www.opengis.net/def/uom/OGC/1.0/>

select ?y ?Gebouwgeo where { ?s a <http://brt.basisregistraties.overheid.nl/def/top10nl#Gebouw>
filter(contains(str(?s), '102696347'))
?s geo:hasGeometry/geo:asWKT ?Gebouwgeo.
?y a brt:Museum;
geo:hasGeometry/geo:asWKT ?Museumgeo.
  FILTER(geof:distance(?Museumgeo, ?Gebouwgeo, uom:metre) < 20000)
```

I get the following error

```
Gateway Time-out (#504)
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

Comment: what means "does not work"? Please show the query. And you should search on the subject shouldn't you?

Comment: Is there a fixed scheme for the URI? If so, you could just build the URI or not? Otherwise, scanning all resources is clearly too expensive and will porbably lead to a timeout.

Comment: `@id` is just some JSON-LD specific thing - it has nothing to do with the data

Comment: If you are able to restrict the search space, it might work although still slow: `select *
where {
  
 ?s a <http://brt.basisregistraties.overheid.nl/def/top10nl#Gebouw>
  filter(contains(str(?s), "100174287"))
}` - you can see, I restricted the search over *Gebouw*

Comment: @AKSW, I added the query in my post

Comment: Ok, yes the query is empty. But did you look at one of those buildings? There is no such property, so I don't know from where you have it. You can only query data that exists.

Comment: @ According to the following link https://brt.basisregistraties.overheid.nl/def/top10nl, 'identificatie' should be a property of the buildings, if I'm not wrong. By the way, thanks for your above query. It worked for selecting therefore the building with the corresponding numbers, however when I tried to elaborate the query a bit by selecting museum within a certain distance of the selected building, then I got afterwards a time-out error. So I am wondering whether I have written the query rightly. Can I ask this question to you via this question or should I ask the question as a new question?

Comment: This is just the schema which you refer to. In RDF there is no need to "use" all properties. So maybe they didn't for some reason. All I can say is that there is no such property for the houses. You could try to contact the creator/maintainer of the dataset and ask.

Comment: You could extent your question here and show the query with the timeout

Comment: @AKSW I added the elaborative query in the post with the accompanying error I received.

Comment: Yeah, the filter is too expensive. MY question again, why do you need to search for the URI? I mean, the URI scheme is fixed, isn't it? Looks for me like `http://brt.basisregistraties.overheid.nl/top10nl/id/gebouw/{ID}` And you have the ID, right? So, you can easily build the URI in your client application or not?

Comment: this is clearly much more efficient if you have the URI: `select ?s ?y where { 
  VALUES ?s {<http://brt.basisregistraties.overheid.nl/top10nl/id/gebouw/102696347>}
 
?s geo:hasGeometry/geo:asWKT ?Gebouwgeo.
?y a brt:Museum;
geo:hasGeometry/geo:asWKT ?Museumgeo.
  FILTER(geof:distance(?Museumgeo, ?Gebouwgeo, uom:metre) < 20000)
}`

Comment: @AKSW, thank you very much! I was really struggling with this. I didn't know about the Values option, now I don't run into a timeout error ;)  You might want to answer the question and subsequently I might answer your code as accepted answer if you don't mind